# camera in Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC

Tags: c#, exception, camera, pocketpc

I'm developing a `C#, Windows mobile app` and I need to launch my device `camera`:

This is my code:

```
        CameraCaptureDialog ccd = new CameraCaptureDialog();
        ccd.ShowDialog();//<--- 
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ccd.FileName);
```

In the `ccd.ShowDialog();//<---` this line shows me the next exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: An unknown error occurred.`

I dont know if the exception is because of my `Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC` doesn't have the camera built in.
Or what I'm trying to do will never works..

So... Anybody could tell me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the `Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC emulator` doesn't have a `built-in camera`, that's why all my tries were **unsuccessful**..

When I `built` the app, and `installed` it on my `device`, I ran the app and...

## **SURPRISE!!! IT WORKED!!**

So... My conclussion is:

The code lines work! but only on my device, They wont work on the WMPPC emulator...

If somebody has a different answer.. Let me know it.